# How to access .ros/ diretory files?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,

I'm running a node that saving images in .ros/ directory. I want to access these images and visualize it !!

Thank you at advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324220/how-to-access-.ros/-diretory-files-!/) by [massyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/41797/massyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Press `Alt`+`F2` and write this command there with Ubuntu (or you can do with terminal instead of Alt+F2):

```
nautilus ~/.ros
```

This command opens your file manager with the path: `/home/$USER/.ros`

In linux, file/folder names that start with a dot `.` means that they're hidden. You can toggle viewing/hiding hidden files in your file manager `nautilus` by `Ctrl`+`H`.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2019-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [massyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/41797/massyp/) on 2019-05-29**:
I found it now, thanks to you